# Populating dropdown from json

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have following json.

```
{
    "vouchers" : {
         "ca_id" : "5",
    },
    "accounts" : [{
            "id" : "1",
            "ca_code" : "1001",
            "ca_name" : "Sources of Fund"
        }, {

            "id" : "2",
            "ca_code" : "1001.01",
            "ca_name" : "Shareholders' Fund"
        }
    ]
}
```

My router is

```
App.CreditEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({        
    setupController: function(controller, model){
        $.getJSON(rootUrl+'api/voucher/getVoucherWithAccounts', {id: model}, function(data){
            controller.set('content', data);
        });                
    }
});
```

I was trying to populate the dropdown with the above json. So i used

```
{{view Ember.Select
       contentBinding="content.accounts"
       optionValuePath="content.accounts.id"
       optionLabelPath="content.accounts.ca_name"
       valueBinding="content.vouchers.ca_id"
}}
```

but it seems my dropdown is populating empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please add the code explaining how you're linking the JSON to the select. And by empty, are there no options, or are the options blank?

That being said, `optionValuePath` and `optionLabelPath` are relative paths. So hopefully it should be an easy fix.

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="content.accounts"
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.ca_name"
   valueBinding="content.vouchers.ca_id"
}}
```

Comment: I set json in my controller's content. So have the following code in my router. I have edited my question pls have a look